# Remove image using javascript/refresh image on change

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can remove an image using a red box with a white X .

I found this http://codepedia.info/convert-html-to-image-in-jquery-div-or-table-to-jpg-png/.

I would like to know how I can make a red box on the corner everytime a new image is produced. Or if its easier to just refresh the image when changes are applied

Comment: Read the SO question guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="complete/source/path" alt="title">
    <div style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px; color:red; ">X</div>
</div>
```